# Understanding MEF System.Lazy<T,TMetaData>

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, mef

I have been looking at the inner workings of the [StockTrader RI for PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com).

In this RI, MEF and a custom attribute system are used in combination to register views with regions as opposed to hooking up things to the RegionManager in the Module Initializer.

More specifically, there is a `ViewExportAttribute` which implements:

1. `MetaDataAttribute`
2. `IViewRegionRegistration`

The MetaDataAttribute and the "Attribute View" `IViewRegionRegistration` can be leveraged by `System.Lazy<T,TMetaData>` in `AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior` to achieve proper linking of regions and views.

In general the interplay between `System.Lazy<T,TMetaData>` and the actual metadata is elaborated [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata), more specifically the section "Using Strongly-typed Metadata".

To be clear, I understand the intent of Lazy and it clearly works. However, what I completely do not understand is **where and how the link occurs between the metadata view supplied by the attribute (which is just an interface) and filling the TMetaData properties with the actual data supplied by the MetaDataAttribute**.

To make my request even clearer, from the [previously referenced example](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata):

First, an interface is defined that can serve as a sort of template to pass certain metadata:

```
public interface IMessageSenderCapabilities
{
    MessageTransport Transport { get; }
    bool IsSecure { get; }
}
```

Next, A corresponding MetaDataAttribute is defined (which has the same properties as the previous interface)

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class MessageSenderAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public MessageSenderAttribute() : base(typeof(IMessageSender)) { }
    public MessageTransport Transport { get; set; }
    public bool IsSecure { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute can be used in an export, where actual values are set for the attribute properties:

```
[MessageSender(Transport=MessageTransport.Smtp, IsSecure=true)]
public class SecureEmailSender : IMessageSender
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Now finally, we can do some importing:

```
public class HttpServerHealthMonitor
{
    [ImportMany]
    public Lazy<IMessageSender, IMessageSenderCapabilities>[] Senders { get; set; }

    public void SendNotification()
    {
        foreach(var sender in Senders)
        {
            if (sender.Metadata.Transport == MessageTransport.Smtp && 
                sender.Metadata.IsSecure)
            {
                var messageSender = sender.Value;
                messageSender.Send("Server is fine");

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this last step: `sender.Metadata.Transport` is evaluated on that very Lazy<>. Therefore, somewhere along the way, Lazy is made aware of the actual values of the metadata, not just the interface it gets passed. **I want to understand how that happens**, who or what is responsible for that. Even if it is just a very general flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more Reflector I think I can start to formulate an answer, although it turns out a lot of things are happening so this answer might evolve. I am writing it down hear for the benefit of learning this myself.

1. `MEFBootsrapper.Run()`

   ...
2. `MEFBootstrapper.Container.GetExports(...)` because `CompositionContainer : ExportProvider, ...` and ExportProvider defines `public Lazy<T, TMetadataView> GetExport<T, TMetadataView>()`.
3. Next `private Lazy<T, TMetadataView> GetExportCore<T, TMetadataView>(string contractName)`
4. Next `internal static Lazy<T, M> CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM<T, M>(Export export)`
5. In here, `AttributedModelServices.GetMetadataView<M>(export.Metadata)` where M is the type of the MetaDataView. Whereas export is itself of type `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export` and this has a field `ExportDefenition` of which an inherited `AttributedExportDefenition` exists.
6. `AttributedExportDefenition.MetaData` whose getter contains `this._member.TryExportMetadataForMember(out strs);`
7. `TryExportMetadataForMember(...)` finally has a check `type.IsAttributeDefined<MetadataAttributeAttribute>` to see if there is a MetadataAttribute applied such as for `MessageSenderAttribute` in the question.

So this is more or less (very roughly) how we get to the actual metadata on the export and so probably with some more detours these exported metadata will also reach the Lazy although I am still to find out how that would work exactly.

Any feedback would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what is going on with the code in my original question has spawned another question:

There is a subtle difference between the StockTrader RI and the example provided in the [MEF Documentation](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata)

In Stocktrader, `ViewExportAttribute` is defined:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
 [MetadataAttribute]
 public sealed class ViewExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IViewRegionRegistration
 {
    ... omitted for brevity ...
 }
```

The MEF docs give a similar example (also in the original question):

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class MessageSenderAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public MessageSenderAttribute() : base(typeof(IMessageSender)) { }
    public MessageTransport Transport { get; set; }
    public bool IsSecure { get; set; }
}
```

So with the above code blocks, the difference is that in the first case, the attribute derives from the Interface that defines the "metadata view" whereas in the second example, this is not the case; The attribute just has the same properties as the `IMessageSenderCapabilities` interface.

"No big deal" you would think but then in StockTrader RI:

```
[ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
public Lazy<object, IViewRegionRegistration>[] RegisteredViews { get; set; }
```

Whereas in the MEF Example:

```
[ImportMany]
public Lazy<IMessageSender, IMessageSenderCapabilities>[] Senders { get; set; }
```

So here, the difference is that in Stocktrader RI, the type that we are trying to Lazily import is not specified (it is just object) whereas in the second it is defined more specifically (IMessageSender).

The end result is more or less the same, some type is Lazily imported along with metadata.

However, what I would like to also learn is:

1. If the differences at the individual key points in both examples are related.
2. Specifically in the stock trader example, how do we know what to import as Lazy? Is it because the `ViewExportAttribute` specifically derives from `IViewRegionRegistration` that we can have `Lazy<object, ...` later on, i.e. that the system knows what to import because only types with that metadata will be imported? All this without specifying that `object` will actually be views, i.e. UserControls?